# XPath Expression returns 'illegal string specified' in Chrome but not FF

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xpath, greasemonkey, evaluate

so this is an xPath expression which **runs fine in a Firefox userscript** but fails in a (native) chrome userscript:

```
var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate("//a[@class='inline-object' and .[contains(@href,'test.com')] ]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
//just the string:
"//a[@class='inline-object' and .[contains(@href,'test.com')] ]"
```

The error message: 
*Uncaught SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified.*

I've tried several things (e.g. extra brackets), googling and searching on stackoverflow without success. I also tried:

`"//a[@class='inline-object action-card' and .[@href = 'test.com']]"`

which also did not work. Is there someone who can explain this and correct the code?
Thanks in advance

Edit: More important information: The **problem seems to be the 'current node' (the dot)** in the 'and statement'.

2nd Edit: Here's a test-node:
`<a href="test.com" class="inline-object"> text of the testnode </a>`

Comment: Why note merely `//a[@class='inline-object' and contains(@href,'test.com')]`?

Comment: Seems also to cause a 'Uncaught SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified.' error :( The only reason I wrote it that way is to specify that I want the current node to match the and statement not any other (i.e. when using //a instead of . )

Comment: The expression suggested by @RossPatterson is equivalent to yours. I tried it on Chromium and seems to work fine.

Comment: I still can't make mine work (if you suggested that), but the expression by @RossPatterson is working, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath expressions like `.[true()]` are actually illegal (at least in XPath 1.0). Predicates are only allowed

- in [location steps](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Location-Steps) after a NodeTest but not after an AbbreviatedStep like `.`
- after a [FilterExpr](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-FilterExpr) or [PrimaryExpr](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-PrimaryExpr) but not after any other expression

You should simply follow @Ross Patterson's suggestion and write `//a[@class='inline-object' and contains(@href,'test.com')]`. Or, alternatively but more convoluted:

- `self::node()[contains(@href,'test.com')]` or
- `self::*[contains(@href,'test.com')]` or
- `(.)[contains(@href,'test.com')]`

Comment: Thanks, I must have messed up my string, it was somewhat longer and more complicated. Apologies to Ross Patterson. I found little tutorials on the 'and'/more complex statements, I followed http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp but it's clearer now. THANKS!

Comment: For future reference, W3Schools is a very poor resource.  It's information is often incorrect.